# Drupal: customizing user register form

Tags: drupal, user-registration

I want to customize the user/register form.

When the anonymous user goes on this page I don't want to show the tabs `Create new account`, `Log in`, `Request new password`, and don't want to see the fieldset `Account information` with a username and email.

How can I do it in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tabtamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module lets you control what tabs are visible from the admin pages.

I'm not sure if it's possible to remove the user profile page entirely, but a module like [login_destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) or [logintoboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) let you control where the user goes when they log in.